# Build app with api 26 but libs with api 24

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

- I migrated to android studio 3.1
- I use an external dependency which uses API 24. I can not do code changes here.
- I need to build my app with API 26.

is it possible? how can this be done?

During various trials, I got this error

> Gradle: Error: more than one library with the package name
>   'recyclerview'

app build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    implementation project(path: ':libs:externalLib', configuration: 'default')
```

libs:externalLib build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-alpha2'
}
```

Or can I target for API 26 while using 24.x everywhere as a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You 'must' add you library dependencies in app/build.gradle file.

Comment: Yes, I have it please see my edit above for app build.gradle

Comment: How did you add external library ?with android studio's  ' ProjectStructur '  window  or by your own HAND.

Comment: You are right. It built successfully. The error I mentioned above was for different reasons. I accept because you responded and clarified my doubt.

Comment: go to 'ProjactStructure' on tab Dependencies click on the plus button and add your .jar file.

Answer (score 1):

error says `recyclerview` library is added twice first you have added it to your gradle and second your library is adding it.
you have to remove `implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'` from your gradle file and contact developer of library to update his library or yourself update it and change its gradle to use version 26 of `recyclerview` and support `library`